# Wget on Centos 7.2

Tags: wget, centos7

I have a wget inside a php script. (wget connects to the another server to retrieve a data).
from command line php works fine, but when I try to access it in the browser from another computer, php fails because of wget.
All this was working on Centos 5.2 but on Centos 7.2 no way. any idea?
chmod is set 755.

Comment: What user is your server running the php script as?

Comment: the user is root. when I comment wget, php works fine. on the other hand the same wget did its job if I start it from command line

Comment: Apparently the problem is port 8080. but still from command line wget can access http://x.x.x.x:8080 whereas from php it doesnot work

Answer (score 0):

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on

did the trick